# HTML5 Validation not working on Woocommerce cart.php

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, cart

I have a very specific situation where I need users to check on terms & conditions checkbox on the cart page, before they can leave the page or alternatively before they can proceed to checkout.

I modified the cart.php from this:

```
<div class="row cart-totals">                   
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="#update-cart" id="update-cart-btn"><?php _e('Update Cart', 'aurum'); ?></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" id="proceed-to-checkout"><?php _e('Checkout', 'aurum'); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="row cart-totals">

                <!-- Köpvillkor tillgda av mig -->
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                    <p class="terms">
                        <input name="terms" type="checkbox" required class="input-checkbox" id="terms" />
                        <label for="terms" class="checkbox">Jag godkänner härmed Trend House <a href="allmanna-villkor/" title="Allmänna Villkor" target="_blank">Allmänna Villkor</a> & <a href="integritetspolicy/" title="Integritetspolicy" target="_blank">Integritetspolicy</a> samt åtar mig att betala för min order i enlighet med era <a href="betalningsvillkor/" title="Betalningsvillkor" target="_blank">Betalningsvillkor</a> .</label>
                    </p>

                </div>
                <!-- Slut på Köpvillkor tillagda av mig -->

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="#update-cart" id="update-cart-btn"><?php _e('Update Cart', 'aurum'); ?></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" id="proceed-to-checkout"><?php _e('Checkout', 'aurum'); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This isn't working. One can both leave the page or proceed to checkout without checking the checkbox. Why isn't it working and how can I make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The term and condition checkbox only works in checkout, not in cart. There is no validation script or hook on cart pages. because nothing is submitted on cart. There is only ajax events for changing quantities, removing items, adding coupons and set shipping data. So you will have to build your own feature using javascript (certainly ajax).